How can I ensure PopupWindow displays at the top of the screen?
I'm facing an issue with PopupWindow where even after setting its position to (0, 0), it doesn't display at the top of the screen. The status bar is hidden in my activity. How can I ensure PopupWindow displays at the very top of the screen?
I have tried using different parentViews, and these parentViews are correctly displayed at the top-left corner of the screen. However, when I call popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0), the PopupWindow always appears with a gap from the top, exactly the height of the status bar.
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            View contentView= LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.popup_window_content,null,false);
            PopupWindow popupWindow=new PopupWindow(this);
            popupWindow.setContentView(contentView);
            popupWindow.setHeight(ViewUtil.dp2px(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dp_79)));
            popupWindow.setWidth(ViewUtil.dp2px(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.screen_width)));
            View view =mBinding.bg;
            Log.d("debug", "pos: "+view.getX()+" "+view.getY());
            popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);

        }, 1000);

screenshot illustrating the issue

I solved it，it‘s a fool question，just use  statusWindow.setClippingEnabled(false);
